# Spring application duplicating functionality because of ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets, applicationcontext

I've got a Spring application with Hibernate integration, deployed on a JBoss server locally. I configured the app using annotations throughout and a Config.java class for configurations of Spring and Hibernate.

I'm getting this warning in my logs:

> 17:13:18,153  WARN spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope:273 - HHH000233:
> Scoping types to session factory
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4945417e after already
> scoped org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4945417e

When I tried debugging throughout my program, I found out about the place in my program the log was coming from. In one of my servlets, I've got this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    ...
}
```

I've tried instead using

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

in the class, but that breaks my application.

A little more verbose logging:

> 17:57:35,211 DEBUG internal.SessionFactoryImpl:292 - Instantiated session factory
>
> 17:57:35,211 DEBUG spi.TypeConfiguration:146 - Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@42990ff8] to SessionFactoryImpl [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@494db1a3]
>
> 17:57:35,211 DEBUG spi.TypeConfiguration:148 - Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@42990ff8] to SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@494db1a3]
>
> 17:57:35,211 WARN spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope:273 - HHH000233: Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@494db1a3 after already scoped org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@494db1a3
>
> 17:57:35,225 TRACE internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:228 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.persister.spi.PersisterFactory]
>
> 17:57:35,227 TRACE internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:228 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.persister.spi.PersisterClassResolver]

What this all results in is all of my transactions taking place twice, both in my classes and in my database. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I sense, it might be due to, use Controller / RestController annotation for creating your endpoint. Not recommend to create your own Servlet Classes in Spring MVC application.

Comment: This application is not configured as a Spring MVC project. At this point I'm using Spring to integrate with Hibermate. @PrakashAyappan

Comment: Hope, it should be in Spring MVC for a Spring Web Application. Am I missing something in understanding your problem!!!